# Spark Delete Rows

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame containing roughly 20k rows.

I want to delete 186 rows randomly in the dataset.

To understand the context - I am testing a classification model on missing data, and each row has a unix timestamp. 186 rows corresponds to 3 seconds (there are 62 rows of data per second.)

My aim for this is, when data is streaming, it is likely that data will 
be missing for a number of seconds. I am extracting features from a time window, so I want to see how missing data effects model performance.

I think the best approach to this would be to convert to an `rdd` and use the `filter` function, something like this, and put the logic inside the filter function.

`dataFrame.rdd.zipWithIndex().filter(lambda x: )`

But I am stuck with the logic - how do I implement this? (using PySpark)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to do like this:

```
import random
startVal = random.randint(0,dataFrame.count() - 62)
dataFrame.rdd.zipWithIndex()\
             .filter(lambda x: not x[<<index>>] in range(startVal, startVal+62))
```

This should work!

Comment: Hey @Thiago , just have another follow up question. I want  to filter by a column, for example one of my column is a timestamp, to delete 10 seconds worth of rows. I tried to add `.filter("timestamp" in range(startVal, startVal+10))` to delete 10seconds , but it doesn't work .

Comment: Is your column a Int? Or a timestamp type of dataFrame?

Comment: It's an int, (converted it from a unix timestamp by dividing by 1000). because it's time series data, there are many columns within one second, so deleting by count won't work.